# Is there a bookstore app for Ubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation, books

I like the iBooks App in Mac Os X, and the variety of books it allows you to read. I am in search for something similar for Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your in luck, you can find Calibre Ebook library management in Ubuntu software center. It works like a charm.

It also handles a bunch of ebook-reader devices. It reads all (I think) book formats and can convert them too, if your reader does not support a given format.

Comment: 'bookstore app'!, Calibre - to the best of my knowledge is ibook 'management' software.

Comment: Yes and it also have a net-search button to get new books, in mine it dosnt search ibookstore, but I think it can be added,

Comment: Yes, Calibre also lets you search through a number of online book stores if you want to buy a certain book, but the iBooks store is not one of them, nor can you add it. Moreover, Calibre does not handle books with DRM well: you can't read or convert a DRM-encumbered book.

Comment: Sorry about that, you are right it dosn't handle DRM, its a proprietary format! What do you read them uppon?
If it's the ipad why not use the onbord Apple shopping icon?
Unfortunately there is no iTunes app for Ubuntu - strange the Macs run Linux (BSD I think)

Comment: I'm trying to use Calibre but it's design/interface/icons makes my wanna punch it. Not kidding. user-experience/user-design, horrible. Horrible. Horrible.

Comment: Where can i search for online books? Where's that button?

Comment: It's the bluish globe button that says "Get books".

Comment: Yeah, I reseted the interface to default and I saw the button. I had them minimized and no text. Calibre looks like it was made for phone screens, whit there massive buttons. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0):

How about *fbreader* ? It's an ebook reader with a built-in library manager

It does not come with a lot predefined libraries.

However, you can add your favorite OPDS library in there.